# Insert Variable PHP in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

can you help me
i have problem insert variable php into jquery, this my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#add").click(function() {
    var error = <?php echo $reportErr; ?>;
    $("#table").append("<tr><td> <input type='text' name='report[]' /> <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='rem'>-</a>"+error+"</td></tr>");
});
$("#table").on('click','.rem',function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```
<?php 
$report = "error";
$reportErr = $report;
?>
```

Comment: Look at the JavaScript you are generating. Is it what you expect? Look at your JavaScript console? Are there any errors? Frankly - do some debugging yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, you have a syntax error. Your string needs to be in quotes.

Try `var error = "<?php echo $reportErr; ?>";`